# Make selection highlight visible for hidden text

Tags: css, image, hidden, textselection

There is a manuscript book. I need to publish this book in the website. I have text version of this book, and I have the letter positions on the page. I'm trying to let users to select the text over the page image. But users must see only manuscript page image. I did a little workaround like that:

```
<div style="background:url(manuscript_page_with_text.jpg)">
    <p style="color: transparent; position: relative; top:...px; left:...px">The text of the page</p>
</div>
```

I can move this transparent text to exact position on the page image which contains manuscript version of the text. But, when I select the text, it appears over the page image.

When a user selects the text on the image, he/she must see only selection color over the image and actually must select the hidden text. By this way, users can use text operations like ctrl+c.

I need a CSS or Javascript solution for this work. I'm waiting your precious answers.

Comment: i jsfiddle would really help, or rewrite your question, i got lost half way into it just because of how it's written.

Comment: So you're showing an image of the book, with an overlay of the actual text, but the text is invisible.  You want to be able to drag the mouse to select the text and show the selection area, but not show the highlighted text?  Am I getting all this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html) has the solution:

```
p::-moz-selection { color: transparent }
p::-webkit-selection { color: transparent }
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<span style="display:inline-block; width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden">\**I can not be seen, but will be copied!**</span>
```

Comment: On the importance of good titles, this is the answer I would expect from this question upon finding it on google, but it's not what was actually being asked

Answer (score 1):

If the window is active, it works on webkit and mozilla. But if the window is inactive, it works only on webkit. Firefox has a bug on that. And totally forget IE, so I have to try implementing this in javascript.

```
p::selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
p::-moz-selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
p::-webkit-selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

p::selection:window-inactive {
    background:#cc0000;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
p::-moz-selection:window-inactive {
    background:#cc0000;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
p::-moz-selection:-moz-window-inactive {
    background:#cc0000;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
p::-webkit-selection:window-inactive {
    background:#cc0000;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```